# std::vector initialization move/copy constructor of the element

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, copy-elision

I have this piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Foo{
public:
    Foo() noexcept {cout << "ctor" << endl;}
    Foo(const Foo&) noexcept {cout << "copy ctor" << endl;}
    Foo(Foo&&) noexcept {cout << "move ctor" << endl;}

    Foo& operator=(Foo&&) noexcept {cout << "move assn" << endl; return *this;}
    Foo& operator=(const Foo&) noexcept {cout << "copy assn" << endl; return *this;}

    ~Foo() noexcept {cout << "dtor" << endl;}
};


int main()
{   
    Foo foo;

    vector<Foo> v;
    v.push_back(std::move(foo)); 

    // comment the above 2 lines and replace by
    // vector<Foo> v{std::move(foo)}; 
}
```

The output is what I expect (compiled with `g++ -std=c++11 --no-elide-constructors`, same output without the flag)

```
ctor
move ctor
dtor
dtor
```

Now instead of using `push_back` initialize directly the vector `v` as

```
vector<Foo> v{std::move(foo)};
```

I do not understand why I get the outputs:

1) (without `--no-elide-constructors`)

```
ctor
move ctor
copy ctor
dtor
dtor
dtor
```

2) (with `--no-elide-constructors`)

```
ctor
move ctor
move ctor
copy ctor
dtor
dtor
dtor
dtor
```

In the first case, why is the copy ctor invoked? And in the second case, when the compiler does not perform elision, I have absolutely no idea why the move ctor is invoked twice. Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
vector<Foo> v{std::move(foo)};
```

Here you're calling the vector constructor that takes an `std::initializer_list`. An initializer list only allows `const` access to its elements, so the `vector` is going to have to copy each element from the `initializer_list` to its own storage. That's what causes the call to the copy constructor.

From *§8.5.4/5 [dcl.init.list]*

> An object of type `std::initializer_list<E>` is constructed from an initializer list as if the implementation allocated a temporary array of **`N` elements of type `const E`**, where `N` is the number of elements in the initializer list.

See also https://tristanbrindle.com/posts/beware-copies-initializer-list

---

As for the extra move constructor call with `-fno-elide-constructors`, this was discussed in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24753189/241631) a couple of days ago. It seems as though g++ takes a very literal approach to the example implementation of an `initializer_list` shown in the standard in same section I've quoted above.

The same example, when [compiled using clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3473d795c6da3fd3), doesn't produce the extra move constructor call.

Comment: Ohhh, got it... The syntax `{...}` for uniform initialization is quite tricky, and I now realized that `vector` is not an aggregate. And yes, same on my clang, no extra move. Great answer, thanks!

Comment: I agree with T.C.: the fact that gcc produces two move constructor calls seems like a bug. But I suppose as long as this behaviour is only observable when you pass `-fno-elide-constructors`, there's no problem.

Comment: T.C.'s answer nails it, I agree that clang's behaviour seems correct. The following code should be the same: `Foo arr[1] = { std::move(foo) }; vector<Foo> v(arr, arr + 1);`   . The `initializer_list` should only serve the purpose of holding `arr` and `arr + 1`, not moving/copying the elements.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I agree, even if gcc'c behavior is not incorrect, it is definitely strange, clang's seems more intuitive. Anyway, as Brian says, as long as it only happens with `-fno-elide-constructors`, it's unlikely to bother anyone.

Answer (score 3):

The containers try *very* hard to make sure they remain usable should an exception occur.  As part of this, they'll only use `std::move` internally if your class' move constructor is exception safe.  If it is not, (or it can't tell), it will copy just to be safe.

The correct move operations are

```
Foo(Foo&&) noexcept {cout << "move ctor" << endl;}
Foo& operator=(Foo&&) noexcept {cout << "move assn" << endl;}
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed it, now all of the ctors (together with the added `operator=`) are marked as `noexcept`, however I still get exactly the same output (cases 1) and 2) above). I use `g++4.9` btw.

Comment: @vsoftco: Praetorian figured it out, click accept on his answer.