# const vector of Pointers to C-Style Array Elements

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, initialization, initializer-list

Say I have a C-style array like this: `int foo[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};`

Now I want to construct a `const std::vector<int*> pFoo{&foo[0], &foo[1], &foo[2], &foo[3], &foo[4]};`

I can use the `initializer_list` as long as I know all the elements. But say that I was just passed `foo` and it's size. Can I initialize `pFoo` without knowing the size of `foo` at design time?

Comment: do you mean size as in number of elements in array (5) or size of int?

Comment: you can initialise a vector by using start and end iterators vector<int*>(int* start,int* end) - this assumes they are contiguous in memory

Comment: @Jimmy You're talking about using `std::vector`'s iterator ctor I believe, which won't work cause I'm constructing a `std::vector` of `int*`s *not* a `std::vector` of `int`s.

Comment: You can probably use `boost:: transform_iterator` to adapt `begin(foo)` and `end(foo)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a "proxy" function that initializes your vector. This uses [template deduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437150/can-someone-explain-this-template-code-that-gives-me-the-size-of-an-array) to find the size of the array automatically.

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
std::vector<int*> init_vector(T (&foo)[N])
{
    std::vector<int*> vec;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        vec.push_back(&foo[i]);
    }
    return vec;
}

int main()
{
    int foo[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    const std::vector<int*> vec = init_vector(foo);
    for (auto v : vec) std::cout << *v << " ";
}
```

Alternatively, if you're able to use Boost, you can use [boost::make_transform_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html):

```
int* convert_to_ptr(int& i)
{
    return &i;
}

int main()
{
    int foo[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    const std::vector<int*> vec { 
        boost::make_transform_iterator(std::begin(foo), convert_to_ptr),
        boost::make_transform_iterator(std::end(foo),   convert_to_ptr)
    };
```

Comment: I have to say that template deduction is pretty cool. However, not quite what I was looking for. That can be just above the definition of `vec` without a templatized function. It requires a copy construction, even if a separate function isn't called. The `boost::make_transform_iterator` is exactly what I'm looking for... but I don't have access to boost :(

Comment: @JonathanMee I believe copy elision is in effect here.