# equivalent of int[] + k on vector in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, vector, array-view

I have an algorithm and I'd like to translate my code so instead of using arrays I'd like to use vectors.

How would you translate this: (the side of b + j and a)

```
find_kth(a, b + j, i, size_b - j, k - j);
```

where

```
int find_kth(int a[], int b[], int size_a, int size_b, int k);
```

into

```
int find_kth(const vector<int>& a, const vector<int>& b, int size_a, int size_b, int k);
```

It must be equivalent so calls like this return the same value as if I were using arrays:

```
min(a[0], b[0]);
```

Comment: The `+j` is basically defining where in the vector it should start. You can either create a new vector starting from `j`, or passing `j` to the function and use it internally. BTW, you wont need the size anymore.

Comment: `int size_a, int size_b` are not needed as the vector stores its size.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this, I think you can use the `vector::data()` method and keep the function as it is. Or use [iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator#iterator_categories).

Comment: I'm using sizes bcause it's an algorithm to find the k-th element so I the size isn't exactly the size but the size limit I want to explore

Comment: I would recommend either passing `j` as an argument as wendelbsilva recommends, or to change the prototype to actually take raw pointers and use `b.data() + j` (the `data` function gives you the pointer to the data stored in the `vector`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A standard way would be to use iterator ranges instead:

```
template <typename Iterator>
int find_kth(
    Iterator a_begin,
    Iterator a_end,
    Iterator b_begin,
    Iterator b_end,
    int k);
```

This comes in handy, since you need to operate only on a section of a vector. You don't need to split the vector with this approach.

**Improved signature based on SergeyA's comment:**

```
template <typename T>
using is_fwd_it = std::is_base_of<
    std::forward_iterator_tag,
    typename std::iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category>;

template <typename A_It, typename B_It,
    typename = typename std::enable_if<
        is_fwd_it<A_It>::value && is_fwd_it<B_It>::value>::type>
int find_kth(
    A_It a_begin,
    A_It a_end,
    B_It b_begin,
    B_It b_end,
    int k);
```

You can also add another template parameter, or use `std::iterator_traits` to get the `value_type`, instead of having `int`.

Comment: While I did upvote, you do not technically need two groups of iterators to be of the same type. And you want them to be specific iterators - forward iterators, for instance. So your find_kth could be improved :)

Comment: it worked! could you give me a little explain about what does template mean or does and why did I have to add it? it didn't work without adding template then adding it like you, it worked. I couldn't add iterator as a parameter otherwise.

Comment: Well, template here allows you to use this function with all kinds of `Iterator` types for which the code in it compiles. May you decide to use `vector<integer_other_than_int>` for example, you don't need to change the function. You should look up templates for more info...

Comment: @SergeyA On that second part, do you mean SFINAE? What benefit comes from that? One can just document what minimum iterator type it requires (like STL implementations?)

Comment: @LogicStuff, STL was designed done in 98 (or something). Now we do have concepts, don't we?

Comment: @SergeyA Check the updated answer. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: @LogicStuff, I do like it. Though I already upvoted, so I can't upvote any more :)

Answer (score 5):

Use a function template:

```
template <typename Iterator>
int find_kth(Iterator a, Iterator b, int size_a, int size_b, int k)
{
  ...
}
```

You can make it more general by using two types of iterators.

```
template <typename IteratorA, typename IteratorB>
int find_kth(IteratorA a, IteratorB b, int size_a, int size_b, int k)
{
  ...
}
```

This allows you the flexibility of using `std::vector<int>` for `a` and an array of `int` for `b`, and vice versa.

Comment: it worked! but as I asked to LogicStuff on the other reply, could him or you explain the use of template? I'd be very thankful!

Comment: @DanielRocaLopez, Take a look at [Iterator Concept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Iterator) and [the C++ algorithms library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm). Hopefully those pages will answer your questions.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `vector<int> const&` and `int size` with an `array_view<const int>`.

An `array_view<T>` is a class that stores a pair of pointers (`b` and `e`), and exposes `[]` and `.size()` and `begin()` and `end()` and `front()` and `back()` and `empty()`.  It has implicit constructors from `std::vector<T>&`, `std::vector<remove_const_T> const&`, `T(&)[N]`, `std::array<T,N>&`, `std::array<remove_const_T,N>const&`, and from `T*, T*` and `T*, size_t`.

Methods like `array_view<T> without_front(size_t=1)` and `array_view<T> without_back(size_t=1)` are also useful.

There is a `std::experimental::array_view` that also supports multi-dimensional arrays, or you can roll your own.  [Here is one I posted on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26457782/1774667), where it solves a different problem.  It doesn't have `without_front`, but that is easy to write (it depends on how safe you want it to be -- I'd go for fully safe, where it refuses to return a malformed array view and instead returns an empty one, because the check is cheap).

Use looks like:

```
int find_kth(array_view<int const> a, array_view<int const> b, int k){
  // ...
  find_kth(a, b.without_front(j), k-j);
  // ...
}
```

which I find slick.  If you want to pass raw arrays, just `{arr, size}` and it becomes an `array_view`.  If you want to pass a vector, it implicitly converts.

Answer (score 0):

Simply translate the `vector<int>` to an array, something like:

```
vector<int> v;
vector<int> w;
// ...
find_kth(&v[0], &w[0] + j, i, w.size() - j, k - j);
```