# initializer_list<T> can't convert to initializer_list<U>, but T convertable to U

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

Considering the following code snippet...

```
void boo(std::initializer_list<unsigned> l)
{
}

template <class T>
void foo(std::initializer_list<T> l)
{
    //Even though T is convertable, initializer list is not...:-(
    boo(move(l));
}

int main()
{
    foo({1u,2u,3u}); //Compiles fine as expected
    foo({1,2,3}); //Fails to compile at line 9... - could not convert...
    return 0;
}
```

... I'm surprised that `initializer_list<int>` is not convertible to `initializer_list<unsigned>`, event though int converts to unsigned.

I've been wondering in what way one can write foo to allow the conversion. Can one somehow unwrap the list having the wrong type and recreate a new list with the right type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can't unpack initializer list during compile time (to perform neccessary conversion), you can create it the way you want it to be. Consider following code:

```
#include <initializer_list>
void boo(std::initializer_list<unsigned> l);

template <class... T>
void foo(T... l)
{
  boo({static_cast<unsigned int>(l)...});
}

int main()
{
    foo(1,2,3);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Nope.  Constructing an initializer list requires a compile-time known length, and consuming an initializer list you do not have a compile-time known length.

initializer lists are intended for "user-facing" operations, where the user is the consumer of your interface.  Using them internally like that doesn't work well.

An approach you can use is to write an [`array_view<T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26457782/1774667) type that wraps a range of contiguous memory (an initializer list, a vector, a std array, or a C array are all examples of this) in a range-view like way (with begin, end, data, size, empty, front, back methods.  Iterators are pointers).

Then give it implicit converting ctors from `vector<T>&`, `vector<std::remove_const_t<T>> const&`, `initializer_list<std::remove_const_t<T>>` etc.

```
void boo(array_view<const unsigned> l)
{
}

template <class T>
void foo(std::initializer_list<T> l)
{
  boo(std::vector<unsigned>{l.begin(), l.end()});
}
```

goes an reallocates a new buffer of `unsigned` values based off whatever was in `l` and passes it to `boo`.  `boo` consumes an `array_view<unsigned const>`, which can convert from a `vector` or an `initializer_list` of `unsigned`.

We can then write `maybe_convert_list`:

```
template <class T, class U, class...LowPrecidence>
std::vector<T> maybe_convert_list(std::initializer_list<U> l, LowPrecidence&&...)
{
  return {l.begin(), l.end()};
}
template <class T>
std::initializer_list<T> maybe_convert_list(std::initializer_list<T> l)
{
  return l;
}

template <class T>
void foo(std::initializer_list<T> l)
{
  boo(maybe_convert_list<unsigned>(l));
}
```

or somesuch.  It leaves `initializer_list<unsigned>` alone.  For other types of lists, it converts it to a `std::vector<unsigned>`.

Answer (score 2):

A class `Foo<T>` is not convertible to `Foo<U>`, even though `T` is convertible to `U`. For the compiler, different types in the template instantiation give rise to instances of unrelated types.

So in your case, `foo({1,2,3})` deduces `T` as `int`, so the argument of `foo` has the type `initializer_list<int>`. You then try to pass that to `boo`, which takes an `initializer_list<unsigned>`, which is **unrelated** to `initializer_list<int>`, hence the compile error.

You can probably avoid this headache via *template specialization* instead, i.e. specialize your `foo` for the `unsigned` type:

```
template<>
void foo<unsigned>(std::initializer_list<unsigned>)
{
    // specialization here
}
```

Comment: @WernerErasmus Not sure I understand the `std::shared_ptr` conversion you are talking about...

Comment: My apologies. I' m wrong - I was confused with normal Derived to base conversion.

Comment: @WernerErasmus Ohh yes, that's a different story, `T` is still deduced as `Base*` in that case, but then internally the `shared_ptr` can use `Base*` to access the virtual interface of a  `Derived`.

Answer (score 2):

In short, this conversion cannot be done. Once you have a `std::initializer_list<int>` object, there is no way to use it to synthesize a `std::initializer_list<unsigned>`. You can iterate through it but the problem is that the information about the size is not available statically so there's no way to generate from one `std::initializer_list` object a braced-enclosed list of initializers with which to construct a different `std::initializer_list` object.

If `boo` needs to receive `std::initializer_list<unsigned>`, then `foo` should have a parameter of type `std::initializer_list<unsigned>`. You can convert `{1, 2, 3}` to `std::initializer_list<unsigned>`. But once you deduce it as `std::initializer_list<int>` this possibility disappears.