# Why can my compiler not figure out this conversion, when does it exist?

Tags: c++, casting, initializer-list

It looks like when I create a `std::initializer_list<B*>` where `class B` is derived from `class A` and pass this to a function which accepts a `std::initializer_list<A*>`, the compiler gets confused. If, however, I create a `std::initializer_list<B*>` in-place with brace initializers (which I'd assume makes a temporary `std::initializer_list`) it's able to convert it just fine.

Specifically it seems to be unable to convert `std::initializer_list<B*>` to `std::initializer_list<A*>`, even though some conversion clearly exists as evidenced by the one working function call here.

What's the explanation for this behavior?

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>


class A {
public:
    A() {}
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B() {}
};

using namespace std;

void do_nothing(std::initializer_list<A*> l) {

}

int main() {
    B* b1;
    B* b2;

    std::initializer_list<B*> blist = {b1, b2};


    //error, note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 
    //'initializer_list<B *>' to 'initializer_list<A *>' for 1st argument

    //do_nothing(blist);

    //Totally fine, handles conversion.
    do_nothing({b1, b2});

    return 0;
}
```

[Try it here.](https://godbolt.org/z/iIrEoP)

edit:

As a workaround doing something like this
`std::initializer_list<A*> alist = {b1, b2};` 
seems to be accepted by `do_nothing()` but I'm still curious about the behavior.

Comment: Very similar/duplicate: [I want a vector of derived class pointers as base class pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18223036/i-want-a-vector-of-derived-class-pointers-as-base-class-pointers)

Comment: Interesting. It seems `std::initializer_list` does not have a corresponding constructor, however. I'm actually able to get around this by declaring the list with `<A*>`, but I'm still curious about why the behavior occurs.

Comment: Brace-init list `{b1, b2}` does not create an instance of `std::initializer_list<B*>`. Rather, it is used to initialize whatever it's an initializer for - in this case, the parameter of type `std::initializer_list<A*>`

Comment: Thanks @IgorTandetnik that makes sense. I just discovered I can do `std::initializer_list<A*> list = {b1, b2}` which solves this issue for me but I'm still curious about why a conversion wasn't implemented in the language.

Comment: `B *` may be converted implicitly to `A *` since `B` inherits from `A`.   However, `initializer_list<B *>` cannot be implicitly converted to `initializer_list<A *>` since `initializer_list<B *>` does not inherit from `initializer_list<A *>`.

Comment: It is little bit tricky and need enable_if for initializer_list. Consider trying it and contribute https://github.com/microsoft/STL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for this is that the initializer list here

```
do_nothing({b1, b2});
```

is of a different type than

```
std::initializer_list<B*> blist = {b1, b2};
```

Since `do_nothing` takes a `std::initializer_list<A*>` the braced initialization list in your function call (`do_nothing({b1, b2})`) is used to construct the `std::initializer_list<A*>` from your function parameter. This works, because `B*` is implicitly convertible to `A*`. However, `std::initializer_list<B*>` is not implicitly convertible to `std::initializer_list<A*>`, hence you get that compiler error.

Lets write some pseudo-code to demonstrate what happens. First we take a look at the working part of the code:

```
do_nothing({b1, b2});  // call the function with a braced-init-list

// pseudo code starts here

do_nothing({b1, b2}):                       // we enter the function, here comes our braced-init-list
   std::initializer_list<A*> l {b1, b2};    // this is our function parameter that gets initialized with whatever is in that braced-init-list
   ...                                      // run the actual function body
```

and now the one that doesn't work:

```
std::initializer_list<B*> blist = {b1, b2}; // creates an actual initializer_list
do_nothing(blist);                          // call the function with the initializer_list, NOT a braced-init-list

// pseudo code starts here

do_nothing(blist):                      // we enter the function, here comes our initializer_list
   std::initializer_list<A*> l = blist; // now we try to convert an initializer_list<B*> to an initializer_list<A*> which simply isn't possible
   ...                                  // we get a compiler error saying we can't convert between initializer_list<B*> and initializer_list<A*>
```

Note the terms *braced-init-list* and *initializer_list*. While looking similar, those are two very different things.

A *braced-init-list* is a pair of curly braces with values in between, something like this:

```
{ 1, 2, 3, 4 }
```

or this:

```
{ 1, 3.14, "different types" }
```

it is a special construct used for initialization that has its own rules in the C++ language.

On the other hand, `std::initializer_list` is just a type (actually a template but we ignore that fact here as it doesn't really matter). From that type you can create an object (like you did with your `blist`) and **initialize** that object. And because *braced-init-list* is a form of initialization we can use it on the `std::initializer_list`:

```
std::initializer_list<int> my_list = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

Because C++ has a special rule that allows us to initialize each function argument with a *braced-init-list*, `do_nothing({b1, b2});` compiles. This also works for multiple arguments:

```
void do_something(std::vector<int> vec, std::tuple<int, std::string, std::string> tup) 
{ 
    // ...
}

do_something({1, 2, 3, 4}, {10, "first", "and 2nd string"});
```

or nested initialization:

```
void do_something(std::tuple<std::tuple<int, std::string>, std::tuple<int, int, int>, double> tup) 
{ 
    // ...
}

do_something({{1, "text"}, {2, 3, 4}, 3.14});
```

Answer (score 4):

We must distinguish between a `std::initializer_list<T>` object, and a *braced-init-list*.

*Braced-init-list*s are enclosed by braces, separated by commas, and are a source-level construct. They can be found in various contexts and their elements do not all need to be the same type. For example

```
std::pair<int, std::string> = {47, "foo"};  // <- braced-init-list
```

When a statement that contains a *braced-init-list* is executed, sometimes a `std::initializer_list<T>` object (for some `T`) is created from the elements of the *braced-init-list*. Those contexts are:

- When a variable declared with type `std::initializer_list<T>` has a *braced-init-list* as its initializer; and
- When an object is declared with `auto` type and is copy-initialized from a nonempty *braced-init-list*.

If the `std::initializer_list<T>` object cannot be created from the *braced-init-list*, a compilation error occurs. For example

```
std::initializer_list<int> l = {47, "foo"};  // error
```

In addition to the above ways of creating a `std::initializer_list` object, there is one additional way: by copying an existing one. This is a shallow copy (it just makes the new object point to the same array as the old one). A copy, of course, does not change the type.

---

Now back to your code. When you try to call the `do_nothing` function with the argument `blist`, you are trying to do something impossible because what you have provided is not something that can be used to create an `std::initializer_list<A*>` object. The only way to create such an object would be from a *braced-init-list* or from an existing `std::initializer_list<A*>` object.

However, passing `{b2, b1}` as the argument works just fine, because it is a *braced-init-list*. Implicit conversions are allowed, from the elements of the *braced-init-list* to the required element type.

Answer (score 1):

`std::initializer_list` is a template.

Generally in C++, `some_template<T>` is unrelated to `some_template<U>` even if `T` is related to `U`.

In the call `do_something({b1, b2})` the compiler actually creates `std::initializer_list<A*>` (after applying [list-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) rules).

You can templatize `do_nothing` to take different types:

```
template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<T, A>::value>>
void do_nothing(std::initializer_list<T*> l) {

}
```

(the optional SFINAE part restricts `T` to types convertible to `A`)

For more possible solutions refer to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34005917/initializer-listt-cant-convert-to-initializer-listu-but-t-convertable-to-u).