# Constrainted auto std::convertible_to with initializer list

Tags: c++, c++20

Hello stackoverflow people, I'm recently trying to learn c++20 constrainted auto as function parameters to reduce the boiler plate code.
I have a class template that is a wrapper for some data types, like `std::int64_t, bool, double, std::string`, will probably add more in the future, and it has a function that takes the data type and an overloaded function that takes a `std::initializer_list<data_t>` for array-ish manipulation.

```cpp
template<typename data_t>
void set_data(data_t a_data)

template<typename data_t>
void set_data(std::initializer_list<data_t> a_dataList)
```

And these works fine if I call these setter functions directly.

In an api class that manages all these data, I have an exposed api that does basically same thing, I have this:

```
template<typename data_t>
void bind(Wrapper<data_t>& a_data, const std::convertible_to<data_t> auto a_value)
{
    a_data.set_data(a_value);
}

template<typename data_t>
void bind(Wrapper<data_t>& a_data, const std::initializer_list<data_t> a_valueList)
{
    a_data.set_data(a_value);
}
```

The first function works as intended, e.g I can pass any convertible data type to an wrapper of `std::int64_t`, but the latter one if I want to pass an initializer_list to it I have to explicitly convert the type to `data_t` like this

```cpp
Wrapper<std::int64_t> iA;

bind(iA, 100); // works
iA.set_data(100) // works

bind(iA, {1,2,3,4,5}); // no
iA.set_data({1,2,3,4,5}); // works
bind(iA, {(std::int64_t)1, (std::int64_t)2, (std::int64_t)3, (std::int64_t)4});
// works
```

So my question finally came out: How do I implement something like `std::convertible_to` with `std::initializer_list` so I don't have to to type cast like above? Or is this doable at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is C++ is deducing `data_t` using both 1st and 2nd arguments.  If they disagree, no cookie.

```
template<typename data_t>
void bind(Wrapper<data_t>& a_data, std::type_identity_t<std::initializer_list<data_t>> a_valueList)
```

this blocks deduction in 2nd argument.

Comment: Thank you, that is a very helpful solution that I have not thought about using type_identity_t to distinguish the deduced parameters

Answer (score 1):

Okay after some digging which I should've done before posting the question, I found this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34006263/17295222

```cpp
template <typename data_t>
void Bind(Wrapper<data_t>& a_data, const std::convertible_to<data_t> auto... a_valueList) noexcept
{
    a_data.set_data({static_cast<data_t>(a_valueList)...});
}
```

All I gotta do is to construct a `std::initializer_list` of the required data_t type in place and skip the list construction when calling the function

```cpp
bind(iA,1,2,3,4,5); // works, no need for brackets
```